# Accessing the result tree from within XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, tree, xslt-1.0

On my website I have different types of headlines, e.g. h1,h2,h3.

However, I also have separate subtitles for those headlines. Each subtitles style relates to the style of the original headline.

Let's say this is my XML code:

```
<content type="standard">
    <title>That is my title</title>
    <subtitle>That's my subtitle</subtitle>
    <section>
        <title>Great headline</title>
        <subtitle>Supported by this nice subtitle</subtitle>
        <para>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet...</para>
        <para>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet...</para>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <title>Did you know?</title>
        <subtitle>I bet you didn't!</subtitle>
        <para>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet...</para>
    </aside>
</content>
```

Now in my XSL code I apply the `<title/>` with special parameters:

```
<xsl:template match="content/section">

    <!--- apply all titles in section --->
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//title">
        <xsl:with-param name="role">h2</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <!--- apply all other stuff --->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content/aside">

    <!--- apply all titles in aside --->
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//title">
        <xsl:with-param name="role">h3</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <!--- apply all other stuff --->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]"/>

</xsl:template>
```

That works fine. But now, I have a generic subtitle template which should decide what to do based on the `role` param the preceding sibling title element has been applied in.

```
<xsl:template match="subtitle">
    <!-- here I want to know:

    what is the local-name()/class attribute
    in the result tree of the preceding-sibling::title in xml

    -->
</xsl:template>
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: You can't, I'd daresay. But do not focus on your solution (which might be the wrong approach) - describe the _problem_ you are trying to solve. Read on: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Well, thanks for you advice. I want the <subtitle/> element to always be applied in _relation_ to the preceding sibling <title/> element, but in the XML code I am not able to say _how_ the <title/> will be applied. It get's determined in XSL.

Comment: The simplest way, IMHO, would be to look at the preceding sibling's **original** properties and take it from there - even if it means making the same decision twice.

Comment: Still, you are not saying what **exactly** you are trying to achieve. Do not say this in a comment. _Show_ it with an edit to your question and actual XSLT code. I believe that your problem can be solved, but you are way off the track.

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I amended my question. Hope you better understand what I want to archive now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you'd like to distinguish `title` elements that are children of the `section` element from those that are children of the `aside` element, right?

Write two separate templates, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="subtitle[parent::aside]">
   <h3><xsl:value-of select="."/><h3>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="subtitle[parent::section]">
   <h2><xsl:value-of select="."/><h2>
</xsl:template>
```

Further, templates to tell apart the subtitles:

```
<xsl:template match="aside/subtitle">
```

and so on.

Then, you can do away with parameters alltogether.

---

Another way to write the templates, as suggested by @Michael Kay:

```
<xsl:template match="aside/title">
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Can also be written match="aside/subtitle", match="section/subtitle", which is perhaps more idiomatic.

Comment: @daniel Thanks for editing. But also leave a comment or consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks so far. I guess my initial request is not possible. I feel like your answer is not the answer to my question. However, your approach is too static. I would like to have one template for all titles/subtitles and the site's template calling this template with individual parameters like I showed in the example above ("apply all titles in section"). I could do the same for the subtitles (but would have loved to avoid/automate that). Do you think I could run into problems by doing so? Thank you!

Comment: Your initial request puts the cart before the horse. Parameters are not worthwhile _per se_ and in this case clearly not needed. In some respects, XSLT is very different from procedural languages. Writing templates is one of them.

Comment: One more thing: Introducing parameters does not automatically make an approach less static.

Comment: I agree on that. For me it's important that other developers understand the codebase so I have a file for each element like title/subtitle where all the templates are in. I also have template files for each page-type (like listpages, detailpages etc.). In those templates I would like to define how a certain element in a certain position should be applied (referring to the element template). Where would you put your templates? However I appreciate your responses and I think it helped me thinking further.

Comment: @MathiasMüller
I'd be interested in knowing what you think is the difference between XSLT and procedural languages. Shall I open a new question for this or is it legit to discuss this in the comments?

Comment: Storing templates in separate files is a good idea - but it does not imply that parameters must be used, except you have named templates that are called. You should avoid lengthy discussion in the comments section. There is no need to ask a question about functional vs. procedural programming - there are plenty of answers to that already - you'll find them yourself. Or else, start a chat.